# Wi-Fi card (Fenvi T919 doesnt work) (BCM4360)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

I use now for a year my Fenvi T919 combi card and inside of macOS, Windows everything works flawless, but in Ubuntu the Wi-Fi feature just doesn't work!

Bluetooth works perfectly fine!

Here is a screenshot of my Additional Drivers tab:

[image: Screenshot]

```
mvg@mvg:~$ lspci -nnk |  grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [106b:0117]
    Kernel modules: bcma
```

> ```
> mvg@mvg:~$ sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl
> modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules
> /5.10.15-051015-generic
> ```

> ```
> mvg@mvg:~$ sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Status
> Status: install ok installed
> ```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` and also: `sudo dpkg -s bcmwl-kernel-source | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 The comment is edited!

Comment: "Module wl not found" Ah, haa! Please run: `sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` I suspect it will throw an error that gives us an answer. I also suspect that the driver suite does not support 5.10.15 kernel version.

Comment: @chili555 thank you so much! This just worked out of the box! Wi-Fi is working now. You saved my day

Comment: @chili555 Hey, after a kernel update I get this error:
https://textuploader.com/18up2
https://textuploader.com/18upv

Do you know how to fix this?
I got the same errors a few months ago in other projects (can't remember which one)

Comment: I notice that you updated to kernel version 5.10, a non-standard version for Ubuntu 20.04. The version of bcmwl-kernel-source that you are trying to install doesn't yet support (compile) on newer non-standard kernels. You might try this: https://www.mail-archive.com/kernel-packages@lists.launchpad.net/msg434172.html I have not tested it. Unless you have a pressing need, I'd suggest that you remove the non-standard 5.10 kernel.

Comment: Hey, thank you but this is the „default“ kernel in 21.04 (and I think in 20.10 too)

Comment: @chili555 Thanks it works!

Comment: My fully updated 20.10 install from default Ubuntu repositories says: `5.8.0-43-generic` You have installed 5.10.0-14-generic which will, I believe, be the version included in 21.04. As of now, 21.04 is a development release and off-topic. In any event, I'm glad it's working.